# Java detect connection errors

Tags: java

I have some *Java* code which reads a *gzip* file from an *URL* and decompress it. How do I make sure that the whole file is read from the connection or how do I make sure that there are no problem with it?

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/de?Debug=1");
    URLConnection myUrlConnection = url.openConnection();
    GZIPInputStream gZIPInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(myUrlConnection.getInputStream());
    StringBuffer decompressedStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    int bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = gZIPInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        String part = new String(buffer, 0 ,bytes_read, "UTF-8");
            decompressedStringBuffer.append(part);
        }
        gZIPInputStream.close();
        String decompressedString = decompressedStringBuffer.toString();

        ...

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The try-catch block are auto-generated by *IntelliJ*. What other types of exceptions should I catch to cover : `connection break`, `partial data received`, `connection timeout`. These are all the problems I could think of. Can you think of others?

Answer (score 3):

If you get to the point where `read()` returns -1 you have the entire file that was sent.

But don't collect it in memory: do something useful with it each time you get a piece: i.e. send it on, or write it to a file, or whatever.

You don't need to catch any more exceptions, and any `IOExceptions` indicate trouble of one kind or another.

Comment: read will only return -1 if the stream supplied to gZIPInputStream is read completely, but how i do i make sure that it is given the complete stream and some end bytes are not missing?

Comment: also to reduce some latency i am planning to write the decompressed stream to a file, later on.

Comment: Missing how? The only way they can be missing is if the server didn't send them, and you can't defend against that. Reading it all into memory first and writing it to a file later on doesn't reduce latency at all, it increases it. You have to read the entire stream before you write anything to the file; and you have to block reading from the network when you could be writing to the file. There is no advantage. And if the data is binary you should not use `String` and `StringBuffer`.

Comment: I wont' read it into memory first, i will be writing it directly into file, but that's a plan for later, right now i just want to cover all edge cases to prevent problems later on.